# Form / ListBox "Insert Into" Syntax Error

Tags: ms-access, insert, vba, syntax-error

I have a database that I am trying to send information contained on a form combined with selected items in a listbox to a table when the user clicks a Send button.  I have the code setup that should copy my information but get a syntax error and I am not sure why... I have tried several different things and can't get it to work.  I have included the code below:

```
Private Sub ctrSend_Click()
Dim intI As Integer
Dim lst As ListBox
Dim varItem As Variant

Set lst = Me![lstShipping]

With lst
    If .ItemsSelected.count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
            CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO ShipInv ([Order], [ShipDate], [BIN], [SKU], [Lot], [QtyProd])" _
            "VALUES ('" & Me.[ctrSOrder] & "'," & Me.[ctrSDate] & ",'" & .Column(0, varItem) & "'," & .Column(1, varItem) & "," & .Column(2, varItem) & "," & .Column(3, varItem) & ");", dbFailOnError
    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a situation like this, I always reccommend using a string to hold the constructed SQL so that you can easily print the string to the immediate window to check how certain values have broken your SQL.

So, try adding

```
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "INSERT INTO ShipInv ([Order], [ShipDate], [BIN], [SKU], [Lot], [QtyProd])" _
        "VALUES ('" & Me.[ctrSOrder] & "'," & Me.[ctrSDate] & ",'" & .Column(0, varItem) & "'," & .Column(1, varItem) & "," & .Column(2, varItem) & "," & .Column(3, varItem) & ");"
Debug.Print strSQL
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL 'remove dbFailOnError temporarily so that failure will stop code
```

My blind guess is that if ShipDate is a date field(not text), you'll need to format that value with `Format(Me.[ctrSDate], "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"` before pasting it into the SQL.

Comment: Its not giving an error any more but it's not generating to the table. `ShipInv` is the name of my Table and `[Order], [ShipDate], [BIN], [SKU], [Lot], [QtyProd]` are the names of the fields. It doesn't need to be the caption names does it to generate the data?  The `Me.[ctrSOrder]` and `Format(Me.[ctrSDate], "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")` are fields on the form where the button is located. The `.Column(0, varItem), etc...` are columns in the listbox I created on the form.  I am just not sure where I am wrong?

Comment: I have been debugging and all the values are going in and the field names seem to be correct but it still isn't generating to the form. I feel like I am missing something simple or a command to send it to the table?

Answer (score 0):

I used a different approach and it works out great...

```
Private Sub ctrSend_Click()
Dim intI As Integer
Dim lst As ListBox
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set lst = Me![lstShipping]
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ShipInv", dbOpenTable)

With lst
    If .ItemsSelected.count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
            rst.AddNew
            rst!Order = Me.[ctrSOrder]
            rst!EntDate = Date
            rst!ShipDate = Me.[ctrSDate]
            rst!BIN = .Column(0, varItem)
            rst!SKU = .Column(1, varItem)
            rst!Lot = .Column(2, varItem)
            rst!QtyProd = .Column(3, varItem)
            rst.Update
    Next
End With
rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing
MsgBox "Warehouse Inventory Updated", vbOKOnly, "Inventory Confirmation"
End Sub
```